# Two network drivers? (Broadcom Network Adapter, and Killer e2200 Controller)

Tags: windows-7, drivers, ethernet, network-adapter

This is making me very confused, I have an alienware laptop, and when I went to the Dell website to download drivers, I found a Broadcom Network Adapter/Bluetooth Combined driver, and a Killer e2200 Gigabit Ethernet Controller. I installed both, the Killer e2200 came with a network manager. My question is, what is the Killer e2200 for? I seem to be able to use the internet fine without it, while if I disable the Broadcom Adapter, I can no longer access the internet. When I typed ipconfig /all into the command prompt, I can't seem to find any mention of the Killer e2200. Is there anyway I can make use of the Killer e2200?

Sorry if this sounds like a dumb question.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you have two network devices. Is the broadcom a wireless device? I'd guess the killer e2200 is your wired interface. By what you've said, it sounds like you're using the broadcom NIC, but not the killer e2200 NIC. Does the e2200 show up in the device manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Killer e2200** is a Gigabit Ethernet Controller developed by Qualcomm. It supports only the motherboards which integrate it. It's generally present in MSI gaming motherboards and let's also note, the Controller is optimized for gaming.

It all depends on what **NIC** (Network Interface Card) you have. If you have a **Killer NIC** (comes along with the on-board motherboard) then only you can use it. It seems that only a few series of Alienwares have embedded Killer NICs and yours is unfortunately not one of them, this is the reason why the **Killer e220 GEC**  is disabled, it has no influence and when it's enabled, it's incompatible. You can safely uninstall the GEC and save space, I guess.

I hope I could help!